# Why video defaultPlaybackRate doesn't work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I saw some examples of defaultPlaybackRate and they say it work on Chrome. So I use their example codes and run on Chrome, it doesn't change the speed to 3.0x when I click the button. Anyone can tell me why?

Here my javascript code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var video = document.getElementById('video');

    $("#speed").click(function() { // button function for 3x fast speed
            video.defaultPlaybackRate=3.0;
    });

});
```

The HTML codes,

```
<button id="speed" type="button">3.0x</button>
```

and

```
<video id="video" width="930" height="500" controls>
        <source src="caption.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="caption.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
        <source src="caption.webm" type="video/webm" >
</video>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because once you change the defaultPlaybackRate you have to load the video again using `video.load();` (or set it before the video has loaded). If you want to change the rate while the video plays, use `playbackRate` instead.

```
 var video = document.getElementById('video');
 $("#speed").click(function () { // button function for 3x fast speed
     video.defaultPlaybackRate = 3.0;
     video.load();
 });
```

or

```
 var video = document.getElementById('video');
 $("#speed").click(function () { // button function for 3x fast speed
     video.playbackRate  = 3.0;
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/54gSP/)**

Comment: do you mean video.playbackRate = 3.0; on second option?